# How to use ALB Ingress without rewriting every helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-alb, ingress

I am trying to use ALB ingress with default helm charts, but struggle to solve simple problems with headers.

In Kubernetes ingress-nginx it's easy to add annotations to add headers (CORS), but with ALB I can't do such a simple thing.

I can solve this problem with the sidecar Nginx container, which will add headers, but it will require rewriting helm recipes or maintaining separate manifests with these containers/services/ingresses. Both ways are evil.

What are other ways available to solve such simple things with ALB ingress controller?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with ALB ingress controller. Sources: [1](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/1516#issuecomment-710705085), [2](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/1005#issuecomment-638426690)